# .NET Core EF Select object where relation has

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I am trying to figure out how to get Models from a DBSet where the Model has a relational Model with a specific property.

Example:

```
List<Person> persons = context.Person.Where(p => p.Properties.Where(p => p.CountryCode == 1)).ToList();
```

A Person can have multiple Properties, and I only want to fetch a list of persons that have properties in a specific country.

Comment: it would be much simpler to answer correct if you provide at least context class and data base tables structure ... If you basically have 2 tables then join will be enough otherwise other solutions needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually try something like that,

```
_unitOfWork.GetRepository<AdvertTrade>()
                .GetQueryable()
                .AsNoTracking()
                // Make sure the advert trade does not have any related to this user
                .Include(at => at.UserRatings)
                .Where(at => at.Id.Equals(userRating.AdvertTradeId))
                .Any(at => at.UserRatings.Any(ur => ur.CreatedBy.Value.Equals(userId) && ur.DeletedOnUtc == null))
```

Instead of spamming .Where(), I made use of Any() to look for nested requirements.

To make things more clear, here's a sample chunk of code, the old code is commented out and you need to **focus** on the commented code (I didn't refactor it because its bad, but because my ERD has changed).

```
var payload = _unitOfWork.GetRepository<CurrencySource>()
                .GetQueryable()
                .AsNoTracking()
                // Make sure all currency sources are not disabled or deleted
                .Where(cs => cs.IsEnabled && cs.DeletedOnUtc == null)
                //.Include(x=>x.CurrencyPairComponents)
                //.ThenInclude(x=>x.CurrencyPair)
                //.ThenInclude(x=>x.PartialCurrencyPairs)
                //.Include(cs => cs.CurrencyPairs)
                //.ThenInclude(cp => cp.PartialCurrencyPairs)
                //.ThenInclude(pcp => pcp.Currency)
                //.Where(cs => cs.CurrencyPairComponents.Select(x=>x.CurrencyPair)
                //    // Make sure all currencypairs are not disabled or deleted
                //    .Any(cp => cp.IsEnabled && cp.DeletedOnUtc == null
                //               &&
                //               // Make sure none of the currency pair's partial currency pair is not disabled or deleted
                //               cp.PartialCurrencyPairs
                //                   .Any(pcp => pcp.Currency.IsEnabled && pcp.Currency.DeletedOnUtc == null)))
                .Select(cs => new
                {
                    id = cs.Id,
                    abbreviation = cs.Abbreviation,
                    name = cs.Name
                    //currencyPairs = cs.CurrencyPairComponents
                    //    .Select(cp => new
                    //    {
                    //        id = cp.Id,
                    //        partialCurrencyPairs = cp.CurrencyPair.PartialCurrencyPairs
                    //            .Select(pcp => new
                    //            {
                    //                currencyId = pcp.CurrencyId,
                    //                currency = new
                    //                {
                    //                    abbrv = pcp.Currency.Abbrv,
                    //                    currencyTypeId = pcp.Currency.CurrencyTypeId,
                    //                    currencyType = new
                    //                    {
                    //                        typeShortForm = pcp.Currency.CurrencyTypeId.GetDisplayName(),
                    //                        name = pcp.Currency.CurrencyTypeId.GetDisplayName()
                    //                    },
                    //                    name = pcp.Currency.Name,
                    //                    walletTypeId = pcp.Currency.WalletTypeId
                    //                },
                    //                isMain = pcp.IsMain
                    //            })
                    //    })
                });
```

Notice that I nested some LINQ declarations.

```
.Where(cs => cs.CurrencyPairComponents.Select(x=>x.CurrencyPair)
                    // Make sure all currencypairs are not disabled or deleted
                    .Any(cp => cp.IsEnabled && cp.DeletedOnUtc == null
                               &&
                               // Make sure none of the currency pair's partial currency pair is not disabled or deleted
                               cp.PartialCurrencyPairs
                                   .Any(pcp => pcp.Currency.IsEnabled && pcp.Currency.DeletedOnUtc == null)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly trying to JOIN.
I think you want (psuedo-code)

```
var persons = (from p in Context.Person
              join pr in Context.Property on p.ID equals pr.PersonID
              where pr.CountryCode == 1
               select p).ToList();
```